# Obtener el codigo (primary key) de un combobox

Tags: java, eclipse, interfaz-gráfica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como obtener el codigo de una combobox al momento de registrar, y se guarde en la base de datos con su codigo que corresponde,no la descripcion.
Este es elcodigo que lleno los combos:

```
//METODO PARA CARGAR EL COMBOBOX "cboNivelArchivo"
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
void CargarComboNivelArchivo() {
    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cn = new MySqlConexion().getConectar();
        String sql = "select * from TB_NIVEL_ARCHIVO_SA";
        pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            combo.addElement(rs.getString(2));
        }
        cboNivelArchivo.removeAllItems();
        cboNivelArchivo.setModel(combo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (pstm != null)
                pstm.close();
            if (cn != null)
                cn.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: como cargas tu combobox? ese valor que deseas es uno tuyo??

Comment: ya he cargado los combos mediante base de datos, lo que quiero saber es como obtener su codigo de cada item que esta en el combo al momento de grabar

Comment: a lo que me refiero es que como le das tus datos a tu combo, es un tipo de adaptador que tiene un nombre y un valor que se llama codigo o algo asi?

Comment: void CargarComboNivelArchivo(){Connection cn = null; PreparedStatement pstm = null; ResultSet rs = null;
try {
combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
cn = new MySqlConexion().getConectar();
String sql = "select * from TB_NIVEL_ARCHIVO_SA";
pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pstm.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()){
combo.addElement(rs.getString(2));}
cboNivelArchivo.removeAllItems();
cboNivelArchivo.setModel(combo);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
finally{try {if (rs != null)rs.close();
if (pstm != null)pstm.close();
if (cn != null)cn.close();
} catch (Exception e2) {

Comment: Por favor agrega tu codigo a tu pregunta!

Comment: Ahora si que agregaste tu codigo, que valor quieres obtener si tu le cargaas siempre el mismo? `rs.getString(2)`

Comment: ese combo en su tabla de base de datos, tiene dos campos, uno es su codigo "01" y el otro la descripcion, el metodo CargarComboNivelArchivo(), me carga la descripcion, pero al momento de grabar quiero que se grabe con su codigo no la descripcion

Comment: A menos que hagas otra consulta a la base de datos (lo cual no me parece la mejor opcion) y obtengas el valor del codigo y no de la descripcion, debes hacer una clase tipo NivelArchivo o algo parecido, con propiedades codigo y descripcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabajar con más de un valor dentro de un `JComboBox` te recomiendo que hagas una clase que contenga el tipo de `Objeto` al cual quieres acceder despues de la seleccion.

```
public class Objeto {
    private String nombre;
    private String codigo;

    public Objeto (String nombre, String codigo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
      return nombre;
    }
}
```

Luego cuando quieras agregar un objeto a tu `ComboBox`

```
comboBox.addItem(new Objeto (rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
```

Y finalmente cuando quieras obtener el o los valores de lo que se selecciono en tu `comboBox`

**EDIT**

Como tu `comboBox` es del tipo `Object` cuando el usuario selecciona un item, tu puedes obtener `getSelectedItem()` y lo guardas en una variable del tipo `Object`, asi puedes acceder a sus propiedades.

```
Objeto object = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
String codigo = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
String nombre = ((Objeto)object).getNombre();
```

**EDIT 2**

Para verificar si hay o no un item seleccionado en tu `comboBox` :

```
if (comboBox.getSelectedItem() == null) {
    //Error
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Como tu quieres tener un valor "de referencia" en tu `comboBox` por ejemplo "Seleccione", te aconsejo que lo agregues tambien como un objeto.

```
comboBox.addItem(new Objeto ("Seleccione....", "0"));
```

Y para evaluar si este fue seleccionado (por ende no debería servir y mandarle una alerta al usuario) simplemente verificas

```
Objeto object = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
String codigo = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
String nombre = ((Objeto)object).getNombre();
if(codigo.equeals("0")){
   //error
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48262/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-obtener-el-codigo-primary-key-de-un-combobox).

Comment: Ya lo cambié y me sigue saliendo el mismo error @sioesi

Comment: @BrunoTorres entra al chat